# When can we exchange the order of integration?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f: \mathbb R ^k\to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous on a compact convex set $H$, and $f = 0$ on the complement of said set. How to prove that $\int_H f$ is independent of the order of integration?

My first guess was to define $\rho (\mathbf{x})=\inf \{|\mathbf x-\mathbf y| : \mathbf y \in \partial H\}$ if $\mathbf x \in H$ and $\rho (\mathbf x)=0$ if $\mathbf x \in H ^c$. Then put $$\phi (t)=\begin{cases} 1 & \delta \le t \\ \frac t \delta & 0 < t < \delta \\ 0 & t=0 \end{cases}$$
and $F(\mathbf x )=\phi ( \rho (\mathbf x)) f(\mathbf x)$. Since $H$ is compact, $H^c$ is open and therefore $F$ is continuous on $H^c$. Since $\phi$, $\rho$ and $f$ are continuous on $H$, then $F$ is continuous on $H$, and it is not difficult to prove that $F$ is also continuous on $\partial H$. For any $\mathbf y \in I^{k-1}$ ($I^{k-1}$ being the $k-1$ cell containing a projection of $H$ onto $\mathbb R ^{k-1}$), the set of $x_k$ such that $F(\mathbf y, x_k) \ne f(\mathbf y, x_k)$ cannot be longer than $2\delta$, since $H$ is convex. Because $|\phi| \le 1$ we know that 
$$\left | \int_{I^k} (F - f) \right| \le 2\delta M$$
Where $M$ is the bound of $f$. Also, $F$ is continuous on $I^{k}$ and the above inequality holds for any order of integration. Which implies that $f$ can be integrated in any order. 

I am not particularly confident that this proof is correct. The convexity of $H$ was barely used, and the way I used it was not very rigorous either. Also, the answer given for this problem was over 14 pages long, using some concepts that were not covered on the book, which makes me doubt my answer even more. Is my proof incomplete or completely incorrect?

Comment: I don't really see where you're dealing with exchanging order of integration at all in your proof. Why not just apply your argument to the original $f$? I don't see where you're using anything different about $F$ and $f$.

Comment: @GregMartin by proving that $F$ is continuous, I showed that the order of integration for $F$ is irrelevant. And since the inequality holds for any order of integration, it shows that the order of integration is also irrelevant for $f$.

Comment: If you know that order of integration for continuous functions is irrelevant, then just apply that to the original $f$, which you have stated is continuous.

Comment: @GregMartin yes, but that statement for continuous functions only holds on $k$ cells, so the strategy was to approximate $f$ by a continuous function $F$ on the $k$ cell to show that their integrals were equal to each other.

Comment: It sure looks like $F$ is defined on $H$, not on $I^k$. And it's not clear what set you're integrating $F-f$ over, and how that relates to these domains. I recommend carefully proofreading your post and making these details clearer.

Comment: If you study measure theory a little bit you will find that the geometry of the domain does not really matter for interchange of order of integration. What matters is that there is not "catastrophic cancellation", meaning that at least one of $f_+$ and $f_-$ has finite integral over the domain (when integrated against the product measure). When this property does not hold, you can choose to integrate over the domain in different "orders" so as to get different results. This is exactly like the classical theorem about rearrangement of conditionally convergent series.

Comment: Such catastrophic cancellation is automatically impossible for a continuous function on a compact set (because such a function is bounded and the domain has finite measure).

Comment: @Ian actually Lebesgue theory is the next chapter of the book and skimming over it I have seen words such as measure and the like, unfortunately, what I would like to do is prove this fact with the tools made available throughout the previous chapters.

Comment: @GregMartin $F$ is defined on all of $\mathbb R^k$ since the functions in its definition are defined over that domain. I am also integrating $F-f$ over any $k$-cell containing $H$. I believe it does not matter which since both functions are zero on the complement of $H$.

Comment: Egh...handling Fubini without measure theory is going to be a serious headache. If you aren't required by your course to do this, I'd suggest you just move ahead to the measure theory chapter before reviewing the general Fubini.

Comment: @Ian this exercise comes from Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis, chapter 10. I am not exactly sure what measure theory is, maybe it comes in one of the previous chapters and I did not notice it. Although if you think it is recommendable to skip these exercises and return to them after finishing the book I will listen to your advice. Now that I think about it, the answers to these exercises did mention something about the boundary of $H$ having measure zero.

Comment: There is a way to do this problem using just Riemann integration, but the result is less general and the proof is more technical. The Lebesgue way is easier (and is covered in Rudin Real & Complex Analysis, if not in PMA).

Comment: @Ian so my proof is incorrect?

Comment: I don't know about your actual proof, I'm just saying that extending the Riemann concept from rectangular prisms to general domains whose boundary has measure zero is going to be a bit involved, and will still not give you the most general possible result (which does not require any geometric constraints whatsoever).